# Reordering items in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, stored-procedures

In database I have a table cars with two columns (Position, CarName)  like:

```
1 | BMW
2 | Mercedes
3 | Honda
4 | Toyota
```

Table could be modified, so adding new row "Audi" should be at the top and reorder the table like:

```
1 | Audi
2 | BMW
3 | Mercedes
4 | Honda
5 | Toyota
```

After deleting "Honda":

```
1 | BMW
2 | Mercedes
3 | Toyota
```

After moving "Honda" row at the top (1st position):

```
1 | Honda
2 | BMW
3 | Mercedes
4 | Toyota
```

After moving "BMW" at second position:

```
1 | Mercedes
2 | BMW
3 | Honda
4 | Toyota
```

What is the best and right way to do in  SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the reason why do you need to do that?

Comment: I think you might need a new column `CarRank` and make it incremental, so that the last insert car will be with the highest car rank. This is how you should think of think business needs.

Comment: Yes, it could be column CarRank, in the example I have just "Position"

Answer (score 2):

The order data is stored in a database table is totally up to the DB engine. You can't predict that.

What you can change is the way the data will be sorted before it is returned to you in your select query. You can use an `order by` clause for that.

Comment: I need do that, because there is no way to sort it by "order by", user at the end need to sort this rows as they want/need.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it like that -- let SQL Server handle your Identity column.  If you want something like this, create a view with the following SQL using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT Row_Number() Over (Order By CarName) Rn, CarName
FROM YourTable
ORDER By CarName
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fca5/1) demonstrating.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have identity key autoincremented, but there is no way to sort it by "order by", user at the end need to sort this rows as they want/need.

Comment: in your example ORDER BY clause is excessive. OVER () forced entire statement to be sorted http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64890/2

Comment: @ihorko -- That's why it's best to use this as a View -- then the user can ORDER BY rn ASC or DESC and CarName ASC or DESC.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko -- yes, I realize for this specific example it is, but OP wants to be able to sort by any field, thus just showing for illustration purposes (ORDER BY CarName DESC or ORDER BY Rn DESC for example).  Best regards.